# Round to nearest whole number PHP

Tags: php

I figure this is easy enough but I am missing something here.  Im using Stripe Connect and trying to calculate an application fee (in cents).  The problem is my application fee sometimes has a decimal so it is throwing an error.  I have tried using [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) which gives me  and [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) but Im still getting a decimal and trailing zero in my answer so it returns an error.

```
$payment =  bcmul($request->amount, 100); //112.00 - Convert to cents for stripe becomes 11200
$applicationFee = $payment * 0.021; //235.2 but should be just 235
print_r($applicationFee); //Should be whole number, round and ceil still provide me with decimal number IE 235.0 instead of 235
```

How can I make sure applicationFee is always a whole number with no decimal and rounded to nearest whole number?

Comment: Do you mean that the issue with `round()` is that it still returns a float, and not an integer - and that's the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct as is described in the [docs for ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php):

> The return value of ceil() is still of type float

The method explanation also tells you that a float is returned:

> float ceil ( float $value )

The return type for `round()` is also shown as a float in the [docs for round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) as below:

> float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )

You could use [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) instead as below:

```
intval($applicationFee);
```

Or try casting to an int as below:

```
(int) $applicationFee
```

If you want to keep your ceil or rounding you can call these first and then cast it as below:

```
intval(ceil($applicationFee));
(int) ceil($applicationFee);
```

Comment: Typecasting or using `intval()` would change the type, but not round anything. It'd just chop off any decimal points. `(int)3.99` would still be `3`.

Comment: In that case run a ceil or round first and then cast it. I will update my answer to explain this

Answer (score 2):

This should work! (using `round()` function)

Documentation: [Round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
$payment = bcmul($request->amount, 100);
$applicationFee = $payment * 0.021;
print_r(round($applicationFee));
```

Comment: And how and why should it work? What did you change? Even if its easy to spot, you should include some text to describe your answer.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone it does. So?

Comment: So he said he didn't want a float and that it is returning 235.0 and not 235

Comment: `round(235.04);` will return 235 only.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone you're confusing data with its representation https://3v4l.org/iO8vc

Comment: In that case user has no issue but he said he used round() and it didnt work

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone it only means they did something else wrong. "but he said he used round() and it didnt work" --- don't trust people.

Comment: I like to trust people in this cruel world but I'm happy to stand corrected this time :-)

Answer (score 1):

round() should do the trick

`$applicationFee = round($payment * 0.021);`

You could add more parameters to round and so allow some decimals sill present in the result.

You say you tried it, but I wonder how.

Note
21 is is some countries the VAT percentage (taxes). Be careful how you round those numbers, as the tax office can be strickt

question: according to the docs round() returns a float, as it can also round to 1 or more decimals. But if the 2nd parameter is omitted you should get a whole number. How does a float equal to 235.0 influence the rest of the script?

Answer (score 1):

Php automatically assigns a data type when you don't specifically tell it.  For this to work you have to assign a data type that allows you to do the calculations you are trying to do.

Insure you dimension them with enough space for your calculations.

Then as a last step round it off to the precision that you desire and print it out.

It is highly unlikely that if you let PHP select the data type that you will get what you want.  You have to carefully select for PHP what data type your variables are instantiated as.